# How to combine two BigQuery queries where I've used different fields to group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table of transactions from a marketplace. It has three fields: buyer_email, seller_email, date.

I would like to know who are the most active buyers and sellers, assuming that buyers can be sellers and that sellers can be buyers. By "most active" I mean the users that have made the most transactions in the last N days - whether they are buyers or sellers.

I wrote this query to get the most active buyers:

```
SELECT buyer_email, COUNT(buyer_email) AS number_of_purchases
FROM table 
GROUP BY buyer_email
ORDER BY COUNT(buyer_email) DESC
```

The results look like this:

```
|      buyer_email                       |     number_of_purchases    |
| -------------------------------------- | -------------------------- |
|          john_doe@gmail.com            |         74                 |
|          alice_smith@gmail.com         |         42                 |
|          orange_delonge@gmail.com      |         31                 |
|          ross_elephant@gmail.com       |         19                 |
```

And I wrote another query to get the list of most active sellers:

```
SELECT seller_email, COUNT(seller_email) AS number_of_sales
FROM table 
GROUP BY seller_email
ORDER BY COUNT(seller_email) DESC
```

The results of which look like this:

```
|      seller_email                  |     number_of_sales    |
| ---------------------------------- | ---------------------- |
|          orange_delonge@gmail.com  |         156            |
|          ross_elephant@gmail.com   |         89             |
|          alice_smith@gmail.com     |         23             |
|          john_doe@gmail.com        |         12             |
```

I would like to combine both query results to get something like this:

```
|      user_email          |  number_of_sales    | number_of_purchases | total    |
| ------------------------ | ------------------- | ------------------- | -------- |
| orange_delonge@gmail.com |         156         |           31        |    187   |
| ross_elephant@gmail.com  |         89          |           19        |    108   | 
| john_doe@gmail.com       |         12          |           74        |    86    |
| alice_smith@gmail.com    |         23          |           42        |    65    |
```

However, there are some things to take into account:

- The cardinality of both sets, buyers and sellers, is not the same.
- There are buyers that aren't sellers, and sellers that aren't buyers. The number_of_sales for the former would be 0, and the number_of_purchases for the latter would be 0 too. This is tricky, as the GROUP BY clause doesn't group by 0-sized groups.

What I've tried:

- Using a JOIN statement ON seller_email = buyer_email, but this gives me as a results the rows where the seller and the buyer are **the same** in a given transaction - people who sell something to themselves.
- Experimenting with UNION, but failing to get anything relevant.

I'm not sure if that's clear, but if anyone could help me achieve the aforementioned result, that would be great.

Comment: I think a union and a pivot is easier than full outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, purchase + sale as total from (
  select buyer_email as user_email, 'purchase' type from your_table
  union all select seller_email, 'sale' from your_table 
)
pivot (count(*) for type in ('purchase', 'sale'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm and it's way simpler than a full outer join.

Answer (score 3):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN.

```sql
WITH
    buyer_data AS (
        SELECT
            buyer_email        AS email,
            COUNT(buyer_email) AS number_of_purchases
        FROM table
        GROUP BY
            buyer_email
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(buyer_email) DESC
    ),
    seller_data AS (
        SELECT
            seller_email        AS email,
            COUNT(seller_email) AS number_of_sales
        FROM table
        GROUP BY
            seller_email
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(seller_email) DESC
    )
SELECT
    COALESCE(buyer_data.email, seller_data.email)                   AS email,
    COALESCE(number_of_purchases, 0)                                AS number_of_purchases,
    COALESCE(number_of_sales, 0)                                    AS number_of_sales,
    COALESCE(number_of_purchases, 0) + COALESCE(number_of_sales, 0) AS total
FROM buyer_data
FULL OUTER JOIN seller_data ON seller_data.email = buyer_data.email
```